# Need first and second tier menus and hovers to remain upon click of third tier

Tags: jquery

I found some awesome code for a three tier menu system and would like to make a few changes, but can't understand how to get it done.

Do anyone have any thoughts on my hope to change the code so that when a user clicks on a third tier menu option (em), the second (i) and first tier (b) menus will remain with there hover states. Currently, when a user clicks on a third tier option, the second tier disappears and the first tier hover is removed.  I am thinking that I need a .click function for the third tier elements, but I'm just not that sure.  My jquery is in the developing stages :)

My .js file is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    closetimer = 0;

    $("#navMenu b").mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(closetimer);
        if ($(this).hasClass('hover')) {
            $("#navMenu ul ul ul:visible").slideUp(500);
            $("#navMenu em").removeClass("hover");
            $("#navMenu ul ul:visible").slideUp(500);
            $("#navMenu i").removeClass("hover");
            $(this).parent().next().fadeOut("slow");
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
        }
        else {
            $("#navMenu b").removeClass();
            $(this).addClass("hover");
            $("#navMenu ul ul ul:visible").slideUp(500);
            $("#navMenu em").removeClass("hover");
            $("#navMenu ul ul:visible").slideUp(500);
            $("#navMenu i").removeClass("hover");
            $("#navMenu ul:visible").fadeOut("slow");
            $(this).parent().next().fadeIn("slow");
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#navMenu i").mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(closetimer);
        if ($(this).hasClass('hover')) {
            $("#navMenu ul ul ul:visible").slideUp(500);
            $("#navMenu em").removeClass("hover");
            $(this).parent().next().slideUp(500);
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
        }
        else {
            $("#navMenu i").removeClass();
            $(this).addClass("hover");
            $("#navMenu ul ul ul:visible").slideUp(500);
            $("#navMenu em").removeClass("hover");
            $("#navMenu ul ul:visible").slideUp(500);
            $(this).parent().next().slideDown(500);
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#navMenu em").mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(closetimer);
        if ($(this).hasClass('hover')) {
            $(this).parent().next().fadeOut("slow");
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
        }
        else {
            $("#navMenu em").removeClass();
            $(this).addClass("hover");
            $("#navMenu ul ul ul:visible").fadeOut("slow");
            $(this).parent().next().fadeIn("slow");
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#navMenu").mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(closetimer);
    });

    $("#navMenu").mouseout(function() {
        closetimer = window.setTimeout(function(){
        $("#navMenu ul ul ul:visible").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#navMenu em").removeClass("hover");
        //$("#navMenu ul ul:visible").slideUp(500);
        //$("#navMenu i").removeClass("hover");
        }, 2000);
    }); 

    $("#navMenu em").click(function() {
        $("#navMenu ul ul ul:visible").fadeOut("slow");
        $(this).parent().next().fadeIn("slow");
        $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
    });

}); //end DOM
```

Had trouble posting my html. Let me know if you need it.

Thank you to anyone who can head me in the right direction.  I so want to learn what I can't seem to figure out!

Comment: Kinda hella hard to follow without the markup to help make sense of it. Bit of a massive code block to digest without comments too. If your HTML isn't formatting properly, it may be because you didn't select it and click the "code" button on the toolbar to format it into a code block.

Comment: I do not have a visible toolbar. I would like to include my HTML and CSS as it is likely critical in solving my problem. Any thought on how to 'find' this toolbar?  Simple things bogging me down...

Answer (score 0):

Removing the line I have specified will stop the second tier disappearing when you hover over the third tier.

```
$("#navMenu em").mouseover(function() {
clearTimeout(closetimer);
    if ($(this).hasClass('hover')) {
        $(this).parent().next().fadeOut("slow");    <-- REMOVE THIS
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    }
    else {
        $("#navMenu em").removeClass();
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $("#navMenu ul ul ul:visible").fadeOut("slow");
        $(this).parent().next().fadeIn("slow");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Also, you might be able to get the hover class to stay on the top tier by adding this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().next().addClass("hover");
```

But I really can't ensure it will work without seeing the HTML.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply.  As soon as I can I will try your suggestions.  I will also try again with my HTML using the 'code' button...hope this works!